# Bootstrap 4.0 navbar menu is not working on multilevel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, menu

I am using bootstrap version 4.0 and overall framework build my site well but  only dropdown menu is not working with level. here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/manish1706/4uejano5/1/)
can anyone fix this issue or it is the fault in newer version?

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse show dropdown" id="navbarCollapse" data-hover="dropdown" data-animations="fadeInDown fadeInRight fadeInUp fadeInLeft" aria-expanded="true">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto mainmenu">
          <li class="nav-item ml-2 mr-2 dropdown ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hotel 111111</a>
            <span class="dropdown-toggle caret" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"></span>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-bottom">
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Geschichte und Tradition</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Inklusiv-Leistungen</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Wohnen 111111</a>
                    <span class="dropdown-toggle caret" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"></span>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-right">
                            <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu show">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Dropdown</a>
                                <span class="dropdown-toggle caret" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true"></span>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-right">
                                    <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Dropdown</a>
                                        <span class="dropdown-toggle caret" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true"></span>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-right">
                                            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Pauscalen</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ml-2 mr-2 dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link js-activated" href="#">Reiten</a>
            <span class="dropdown-toggle caret" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"></span>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-left">
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Geschie und Tradition</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Reitnteuer</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Uere Pferde</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Reitunterricht</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Reithalle</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link js-activated" href="#">Reiten</a>
                  <span class="dropdown-toggle caret" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true"></span>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-right">
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Geschi Tradition</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Reitanteuer</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Pferde</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Reitunterricht</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Reithalle</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ml-2 mr-2 dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kinder</a>
             <span class="dropdown-toggle caret" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true"></span>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-bottom">
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Kintreuung</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Krstammtisch</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">-Aktivprogramm</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ml-2 mr-2 dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Wellness</a>
            <span class="dropdown-toggle caret" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true"></span>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-bottom">
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">SA- und Fitnessbereich</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">S-Kinder</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">SA-Anwendungen</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Badesee</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ml-2 mr-2 dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Aktive</a>
            <span class="dropdown-toggle caret" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true"></span>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-bottom">
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Sommer</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Winter</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ml-2 mr-2"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Region</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: why are you calling the caret icon in a span?

Comment: Is the multilevel menu something you created, or copied from a 3.x snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your multilevel menu according to bootstrap 4 standards-

> Missing elements in your code.

**1. The caret span element is now created with pseduo elements with class `dropdown-toggle` on the anchor tag. So no need to add caret span element.**

**2. The way to call the toggle was incorrect.**

```css
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

li {
  background-color: gray;
}


/* ==========================================================================
   Author's custom styles
   ========================================================================== */

@font-face {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  src: url(../fonts/fontawesome.eot), url(../fonts/fontawesome.ttf) format('truetype'), url(../fonts/fontawesome.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'), url(../fonts/fontawesome.woff) format('woff');
}

body {
  font-size: 18px;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #006633;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

a {
  color: #006633;
}

a:focus,
a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #006633;
}

.line {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 21px auto;
  max-width: 150px;
}

.grey-btn {
  background-color: #999999;
  border: 2px solid white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bg-green {
  background-color: #006633;
}

.check:before {
  content: '\f00c';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #006633;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 15px;
}

.shoe_icon {
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a.more-btn span {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #006633;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 5px;
  white-space: normal;
}

a.more-btn span:hover {
  background-color: #999999;
  color: white;
  border-color: #006633;
}


/*********nav  Bar Css Start Here**********/

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-color: #006633;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  background-image: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler-right {
  background: #0e6f4a;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.main-menu-content li.dropdown a.nav-link {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 0px;
  background-image: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.main-menu-content li.dropdown span {
  float: right;
  padding: 15px 5px 0;
  color: #006633;
}


/* Drop - down menu */

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li a.nav-link {
  color: #006633;
}

.navbar-nav li.active {
  color: white;
  background: #006633;
}

.navbar-toggler span.navbar-toggler-icon:before {
  content: '\f0c9';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 8px;
}


/*.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu{display: block;}
button.navbar-toggler-right:focus {    outline: 5px auto white;}

.dropdown-submenu { position: relative }
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {    top: 0;    left: 100%;    margin-top: -6px;    margin-left: -1px;    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;    -moz-border-radius: 4px;    border-radius: 4px; }
.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu { display: block }
.dropdown-submenu>a:after {    display: block;    content: " ";    float: right;    width: 0;    height: 0;    border-color: transparent;    border-style: solid;    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;    border-left-color: #ccc;    margin-top: 5px;    margin-right: -10px;}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after { border-left-color: #ccc }
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left { float: none }
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {    left: -100%;    margin-left: 10px;    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;    -moz-border-radius: 4px;    border-radius: 4px;}*/


/*********nav  Bar Css End Here**********/


/*Box Container*/

ul.feat-ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.feat-ul li:before {
  content: "";
  background: url(../img/imgpsh_fullsize.png) no-repeat;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  background-size: contain;
  left: -25px;
}

ul.feat-ul li {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/*Box Container*/


/* hover effect of boxs */

.detailsbox-sub {
  background: rgba(0, 102, 51, 0.67) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* padding: 6.5em;  */
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}

.hoverbox {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.hoverbox .detailsbox-sub {
  top: calc(100% - 84px);
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}

.hoverbox:hover .detailsbox-sub {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 85px));
  -ms-transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 85px));
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 85px));
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hoverbox .detailsbox-sub h2 {
  color: white;
}

.detailsbox-sub a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.detailsbox-sub a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #006633;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0px;
  /*font-size: 20px;*/
}

.detailsbox-sub a span:hover {
  background-color: #999999;
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
}

.package-info {
  background-color: #006633;
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}


/*********Booking inquiry Css Starts Here**********/

.bar_tp {
  background: #0e6f4a;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}

.sub h3 {
  color: white;
  margin: 12px 0;
  /*font-size: 20px;*/
}


/*.detailsbox {    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;}*/

.img-responsive.loks {
  margin-top: -14%;
  max-width: 78%;
}

.sub button {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: rgb(153, 153, 153) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #fff !important;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 7px;
}

.sub .form-control {
  -moz-appearance: number-input;
  background: rgb(153, 153, 153) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none !important;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.sub .box select,
.sub .box button {
  width: 110px;
}

.box .date_picker {
  background: rgb(153, 153, 153);
  border-radius: 0;
  /*font-size: 15px;*/
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 110px;
}


/*********Booking inquiry Css Ends Here**********/


/*********Siderbar Unfo Css Starts Here**********/

.siderbar-info-wrapper {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 50;
  background: #006633;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

.siderbar-info-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.siderbar-info-wrapper a span,
.siderbar-info-wrapper div.info-vorteile-btn span {
  /*font-size: 16px; */
  padding: 15px 10px;
  top: 0;
  background: rgb(153, 153, 153);
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 55px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
  transform-origin: right center;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
  transition: transform .5s;
  transition: transform .5s, -webkit-transform .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.siderbar-info-wrapper a:hover span,
.siderbar-info-wrapper div.info-vorteile-btn:hover span {
  webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.siderbar-info-wrapper .siderbar-info-booking,
.siderbar-info-wrapper .siderbar-info-location,
.siderbar-info-wrapper .siderbar-info-phone {
  border-radius: 0;
  background: rgb(153, 153, 153);
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.siderbar-info-wrapper .info-vorteile-btn {
  border-radius: 0;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.siderbar-info-wrapper .siderbar-info-booking:before {
  content: '\f236';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.siderbar-info-wrapper .siderbar-info-location:before {
  content: '\f1b9';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.siderbar-info-wrapper .siderbar-info-phone:before {
  content: '\f095';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.siderbar-info-wrapper .info-vorteile-btn::before {
  content: '\f00c';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #006633;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.close-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #0e6f4a;
}

.close-btn::before {
  content: '\f00d';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.display-none {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .7s;
}

.display-block {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity .7s;
}

.info-action-container {
  background: rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.59);
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 350px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.info-action-inner {
  height: 700px;
}

.info-action-container .vorteile-txt,
.info-action-container .actions-btns,
.info-action-container .social-btns {
  padding: 50px 25px 25px;
}

.info-action-container .vorteile-txt,
.info-action-container .actions-btns {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.vorteile-txt h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.vorteile-txt ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.vorteile-txt ul li:before {
  content: '\f00c';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #5fa32a;
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
  top: 5px;
}

.vorteile-txt ul li {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  /*font-size: 16px;*/
}

.info-action-container .actions-btns a {
  width: 100%;
  background: #006633;
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.info-action-container .actions-btns a:hover {
  background-color: #999999;
  color: #006633;
  border-color: white;
}

.actions-btns a.booking:before,
.actions-btns a.location:before,
.actions-btns a.phone:before {
  content: '\f236';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0px;
}

.info-action-container .actions-btns a.booking:before {
  content: '\f236';
}

.info-action-container .actions-btns a.location:before {
  content: '\f1b9';
}

.info-action-container .actions-btns a.phone:before {
  content: '\f095';
}

.info-action-container .social-btns {
  text-align: center;
}

.info-action-container .social-btns a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.7s ease;
}

.info-action-container .social-btns a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.7s ease;
}

.info-action-container .social-btns a.fb:hover {
  color: #3b5998;
}

.info-action-container .social-btns a.twitter:hover {
  color: #4099ff;
}

.info-action-container .social-btns a.googleplus:hover {
  color: #dc4e41;
}

.info-action-container .social-btns a.pinterest:hover {
  color: #c9151c;
}

.info-action-container .social-btns a.fb:before {
  content: '\f082';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.info-action-container .social-btns a.twitter:before {
  content: '\f081';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.info-action-container .social-btns a.googleplus:before {
  content: '\f0d4';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.info-action-container .social-btns a.pinterest:before {
  content: '\f0d3';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 50px;
}


/*********Siderbar Info Css End Here**********/


/*********Scroll top Css Start Here**********/

#myBtn {
  color: white;
}

a#myBtn:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a#myBtn.scroll-arrow-up:before {
  content: "\f062";
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#myBtn {
  background-color: #999999;
  border: 1px solid white;
  bottom: 20px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
}


/*********Scroll top Css End Here**********/


/* Footer CSS Start Here */

#footer {
  background-color: #006633;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#footer a {
  color: white;
}

#footer a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#footer ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

a.footer-btn:hover span {
  background-color: #006633;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Footer CSS End Here */

.social-menu .social-icons {
  width: 40px;
  max-width: 40px;
  min-width: 40px;
}

.img-responsive.shoe_icon {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.text-data h4 {
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.text-data p {
  color: #006633;
}


/* Inner page Full content with Slider */

.content-full-slider {
  background: rgb(153, 153, 153);
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar-toggleable-md">
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse show dropdown" id="navbarCollapse" data-hover="dropdown" data-animations="fadeInDown fadeInRight fadeInUp fadeInLeft" aria-expanded="true">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto mainmenu">
      <li class="nav-item ml-2 mr-2 dropdown ">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Hotel 111111</a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
          <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Geschichte und Tradition</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Inklusiv-Leistungen</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">Wohnen 111111</a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-right">
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu show">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Dropdown</a>
                <span class="dropdown-toggle caret" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true"></span>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-right">
                  <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Dropdown</a>
                    <span class="dropdown-toggle caret" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true"></span>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-right">
                      <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Pauscalen</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ml-2 mr-2 dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link js-activated dropdown-toggle"  href="#" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Reiten</a>
      
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-left">
          <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Geschie und Tradition</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Reitnteuer</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Uere Pferde</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Reitunterricht</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Reithalle</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link js-activated dropdown-toggle"  href="#" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Reiten</a>
            <span class="dropdown-toggle caret" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true"></span>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-right">
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Geschi Tradition</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Reitanteuer</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Pferde</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Reitunterricht</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Reithalle</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ml-2 mr-2 dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"   href="#" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Kinder</a>
       
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-bottom">
          <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Kintreuung</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Krstammtisch</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">-Aktivprogramm</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ml-2 mr-2 dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  href="#" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Wellness</a>
    
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-bottom">
          <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">SA- und Fitnessbereich</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">S-Kinder</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">SA-Anwendungen</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Badesee</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ml-2 mr-2 dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link"  href="#" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Aktive</a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-bottom">
          <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Sommer</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Winter</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item ml-2 mr-2"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Region</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```